# How to detect larger contours which consists of smaller contours?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

[image: sample image]

I'm quite new to image processing. I am using opencv with python.
I am familiar with the normal way of finding contours, but in this case I want to neglect each square as a contour but want to contour over each said shape as shown.

After thresholding currently I am getting contour of each square.
Is there any easy function in the opencv library to detect these entire big shapes than the small squares.

Comment: Simply take your mask and dilate it. It will expand to fill in the gaps. Then you can erode to remove the additional white pixels it added. Or you can just use dilation with a better kernel for filling in lines.

Comment: Wow! totally forgot about that!

Answer (score 3):

As you want to extract the yellow rectangles regions, so:

```
1. Read
2. Exrtact green channel 
3. Do morph-close-op and threshold
4. Findcontours and filter by Area
```

[image]

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.07 14:04:18 CST
# 2018.01.07 14:20:15 CST

import cv2 

## 1. Read
img = cv2.imread("img01.png")

## 2. Exrtact green channel
g = img[...,1]

## 3. Do morph-close-op and Threshold
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(g,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

th, threshed = cv2.threshold(morphed, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## 4. Findcontours and filter by Area
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

canvas = img.copy()

AREA = img.shape[0]*img.shape[1]/20
for cnt in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) < AREA:
        cv2.drawContours(canvas, [cnt], -1, (0,255,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

## 
cv2.imwrite("res.png", canvas)
```